# Multiple definition when compiling

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

I have these files:

```
main.cpp
headers.h
calculator.h
calculator.cpp
Supported_operators.h
Supported_operators.c
My_Operations.h
My_Operations.cpp
```

My `headers.h` file has (apart from std libs): `#include "Supported_operators.h"` and finally my `Supported_operators.h` has the following:

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR_SUPPORTED_OPERATORS_H
#define CALCULATOR_SUPPORTED_OPERATORS_H

#include "headers.h"
//using directives
class Supported_operator {
//stuff
};

list<Supported_operator> supportedOps = {
                                        Supported_operator('+', 2, 'l'),
                                        Supported_operator('-', 2, 'l'),
                                        Supported_operator('*', 3, 'l'),
                                        Supported_operator('/', 3, 'l'),
                                        Supported_operator('^', 4, 'r')
                                        };

#endif //CALCULATOR_SUPPORTED_OPERATORS_H
```

When I try to compile the program, the compilator says `multiple definition of supportedOps[abi:cxx11]` at my `main()`.

How do I solve this problem?

**Context:** I'm trying to make a calculator. Have to split `string` input into tokens. If token is an operator, do certain operations depending on that operator. So I have to create a container of `SupportedOperator`s and then check if tokened operator is supported and what are its properties.

**EDIT 2:** My `headers.h` file now includes `const list<Supported_operator> supportedOps;` and my `Supported_operators.cpp` now has `list<Supported_operator> supportedOps = { };` but then the `headers.h` triggers error `list does not name a type`.

**EDIT 3:** Changing the declaration in `headers.h` to `extern const std::list<> supportedOps;` now results in a new set of errors - `Supported_operator` was not declared in that scope. I thought I had this covered with `#include "Supported_operators.h` where `Supported_operator` is declared. Am I assuming correctly the compilers doesn't know of class `Supported_operator` yet? How do I work around this?

Comment: `list<Supported_operator> supportedOps` - that thing belongs in a translation unit (i.e a cpp file) and `extern` in the header, *or* an anonymous namespace, *or* as `static`.

Answer (score 0):

You should leave `list<Supported_operator> supportedOps;` in the header and add

```
Supported_operator('+', 2, 'l'),
        Supported_operator('-', 2, 'l'),
        Supported_operator('*', 3, 'l'),
        Supported_operator('/', 3, 'l'),
        Supported_operator('^', 4, 'r')
        };
```

to your Supported_operators.c(pp)

Comment: I tried that but in my `Supported_operators.cpp` where `supportedOps = { Supported_operator('+', 2, 'l'), etc};` are there is now a problem of `Excess elements in scalar initializer` and the compiler also says `supportedOps does not name a type`.

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman list<Supported_operator> supportedOps = {/*your stuff*/};, you need to specify the type of your variable in cpp file.

Comment: Ok, I edited my code, my `headers.h` file now includes `const list<Supported_operator> supportedOps;` and my `Supported_operators.cpp` now has `list<Supported_operator> supportedOps = { };` but then the `headers.h` triggers error `list does not name a type`.

Comment: After adding `extern const std::list<>...` there's a new challenge - apparently `Supported_operator` was not declared in this scope even though I have `#include "Supported_operators.h".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change supportedOps, you can also add const directly in front of the variable.

```
const list<Supported_operator> supportedOps = { }
```

This will pass ODR check, since the variable in all translate units are guaranteed to be the same.